# how to remove an array from an Object containing many arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to remove array that containing 0 value in an object

Example:

`dynamic:{"FIRST":[ 0, 0 ,0 ,0], "TEST": [1, 12,123, 12], "KING": [0 , 0 ,0 ,0], "NEXT": [2, 3,4,55]}`

````
Expected result:- dynamic:{ "TEST": [1, 12,123, 12], "NEXT": [2, 3,4,55] }```
````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use [**Array.prototype.every()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
const obj = { 
    dynamic: {
        "FIRST": [0, 0, 0, 0],
        "TEST": [1, 12, 123, 12],
        "KING": [0, 0, 0, 0],
        "NEXT": [2, 3, 4, 55] 
    }
}

Object.keys(obj['dynamic']).forEach(key => {
    if (obj['dynamic'][key].every(x => x === 0)) {
        delete obj['dynamic'][key];
    }
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: @hari Can you please "unaccept" my answer, by clicking the green checkmark i.e., ✅ , so that it is no longer green?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `Object.enteries` to convert to array from object,
2. then filter the array (use `every` if all `0` or `some` if any one `0`)
3. Convert to object from array using `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const proc = (obj) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([, arr]) => !arr.every((x) => x === 0))
  );

dynamic = {
  FIRST: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  TEST: [1, 12, 123, 12],
  KING: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  NEXT: [2, 3, 4, 55],
};

console.log(proc(dynamic));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get the key and then check the values like this

```js
const dynamic = {
  "FIRST": [0, 0, 0, 0],
  "TEST": [1, 12, 123, 12],
  "KING": [0, 0, 0, 0],
  "NEXT": [2, 3, 4, 55]
}

const result = Object.keys(dynamic).reduce((acc, key) => {
  const val = dynamic[key];
  if (val.some(v => v !== 0)) {
    acc[key] = val;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```